# NGINX why does my redirection from subfolder to ip address not work?

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I have following network situation:
Router 192.168.1.1 (portforwarding 80 to 192.168.1.20 Raspberry)
Raspberry 192.168.1.20 with nginx running.
Synology NAS 192.168.1.10 with "synology drive" service running.

On the Raspberry 192.168.1.20 nginx conf file I have a redirection for the subfolder /drive. Because I want to redirect to the Synology NAS to be able to use the "synology drive" service.

Therefore I've created following entry on the Raspberry nginx server in the conf file:

```
    location ^~ /drive {
    rewrite ^/drive/?(.*)$ 192.168.1.10/$1 permanent;
}
```

This redirection kind of works. But only when I'm on the same local network.
My problem is now that I have a domain name pointing to my router (static ip).
But if i use mydomain.tld/drive then the redirection doesn't work.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [proxy_pass](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) directive

Comment: Thank you @miknik for your input. As I'm not yet familiar with nginx I have booked now a course on udemy.com. And there's a chapter for proxy_pass. So I go through this.